# Wordpress bulk category select when publishing post

Tags: posts, categories, taxonomy, publish

Often I need to attach post to all categories and I have about 200 categories. When I need to select all categories while publishing post , I select categories one by one. How can I add select all toggle above category list. I need this not only for categories but also for custom taxonomy and tags [image]

Comment: Have you tried the plugin [Select All Categories and Taxonomies, Change Checkbox to Radio Buttons](https://wordpress.org/plugins/select-all-categories-and-taxonomies-change-checkbox-to-radio-buttons/)?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks for your attention. I know this plugin but I would prefer without plugin. I dont understand why wordpress has no this basic useful functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default function that renders the categories meta box is [`post_categories_meta_box`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_categories_meta_box/) - it doesn't have any internal hooks we can use to inject our own HTML, so let's create our own meta box handler and just use the function internally:

```php
function wpse_406861_post_categories_meta_box( $post, $args ) {
    post_categories_meta_box( $post, $args );

    echo <<<HTML
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.categorychecklist input[type=checkbox]').forEach(checkbox => checkbox.checked = this.checked);" />
    Select all
</label>
HTML;
}
```

This just adds a simple checkbox at the bottom of the default meta box, with a bit of JS that toggles all the term checkboxes inside it.

And to set this as the default meta box handler for all hierarchical taxonomies, we can use the hook [`register_taxonomy_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_taxonomy_args/) to override the arguments passed to any `register_taxonomy` call:

```php
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function ( $args ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['hierarchical'] ) && empty( $args['meta_box_cb'] ) ) {
        $args['meta_box_cb'] = 'wpse_406861_post_categories_meta_box';
    }

    return $args;
});
```

Comment: thank you so much. it wroks